# Вытащить из бд информацию о пользователях и их последних записях

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, задача - вытащить из БД информацию о пользователях и их последних записях, что имею -

```
SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `news` ON (`users`.`user_name` = `news`.`user_name`) ORDER BY `user_points` DESC HAVING (`news`.`news_date` =  MAX(`news`.`news_date`))
```

Получаю ошибку синтаксиса, в чем может быть проблема? Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Может так?

    SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT news.* FROM news join (SELECT user_name,
         MAX(news_date) AS news_date FROM news GROUP by user_name) a
         ON news.user_name = a.user_name) b 
         ON (`users`.`user_name` = b.`user_name`) ORDER BY `user_points`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заранее проверять синтаксис своего запроса http://developer.mimer.se/validator/parser200x/index.tml#parser